# Different Back color for menu bar in orchard

Tags: orchardcms

How can we style different back colours to MENU bar in Orchard ?
I'm having a menu bar in orchard.
I need to style its background with different colours.

Comment: Use CSS and/or [alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates)

Comment: I tried with CSS, but here the menu items are dynamic comes from database.

Comment: nav ul li a 
    {
        padding:0 18px;       
        color: #333;
        font-size: 1.077em;     
        background-color:#66ccff;
    }                                                                                                                           But its displaying only single colour. I need different colours for all menus.

Comment: Have you tried [alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates)?

Comment: Actually I dont know the concept "Alternatives". Is it not possible with CSS ?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want. You just want to style the menu, or you want every menu item to have a different color? Also, how is your menu built?

Comment: Yes, Every menu item to be in different colour.<nav>
     At the rate    tag.StartElement        
        At the rate    DisplayChildren(Model)
    At the rate    tag.EndElement
</nav>

Comment: To Model I'll get all the menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use CSS for this, something like:

```
nav li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

nav li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

/* etc. */
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/arhrvnrn/)